# Is there a function in aggregate which can count nonzero elements of a column

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data set as follows:

```
         Date        Hour    ID
         2014-01-01   0      0
         2014-01-01   1      0
         2014-01-01   10     0
         2014-01-01   11     0
```

I have a sequence of dates (all days in 2014) and the 24 hours of a day. If ID is zero, it means that no call was received at the corresponding date and time. I want to aggregate the results for each date over the 24 hours and return a new data frame that includes Date and total number of customers called. I simply need to do an aggregate over ID and I wrote the following line of code for that:

```
    SampleData <- aggregate(ID ~ Date, SampleData, length)
```

However, the result is not what I want. I need to count over nonzero IDs for the aggregate but I don't know how to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass `aggregate` a function that counts the number of rows in each day with a non-zero ID:

```
aggregate(ID~Date, data, function(x) sum(x != 0))
#         Date ID
# 1 2014-01-01  2
# 2 2014-01-02  0
```

Data (updated so it has two non-zero IDs and two days):

```
(data = read.table(text="Date        Hour    ID
          2014-01-01   0      0
          2014-01-01   1      1
          2014-01-01   10     2
          2014-01-02   11     0", header=T))
#         Date Hour ID
# 1 2014-01-01    0  0
# 2 2014-01-01    1  1
# 3 2014-01-01   10  2
# 4 2014-01-02   11  0
```

Comment: Hard to infer the OP's intentions or data, but "total number of customers called" might also mean `length(unique(x[x != 0]))`

Comment: @Frank yup, definitely could mean that as well. It didn't help that the example provided only had no-visit observations!